# Calling wait() nulls a variable i've just written

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a synthesizer application that has two oscillators, each running in its own thread. What I want to do is mix the signal from these two oscillators. When an oscillator fills a buffer, it passes it to `SynthMixer` object by invoking its synchronized method `sendBuffer()`.

```
package mixer_test;

public class SynthMixer {

Synth synth;
double[] buffer1, buffer2;
boolean buffersProcessed;


public SynthMixer(Synth synth){

    buffer1 = null;
    buffer2 = null;
    this.synth = synth;
}

public synchronized void sendBuffer(double[] buffer) {

        if (buffer1 == null) {

            buffersProcessed = false;

            buffer1 = new double[Synth.bufferSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < Synth.bufferSize; i++) {
                buffer1[i] = buffer[i];
            }

            try {

                while(!buffersProcessed) {
                    wait();
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {

            buffer2 = buffer;

            mixAndPass();

            buffer1 = null;
            buffer2 = null;

            buffersProcessed = true;
            notify();
        }
}

private void mixAndPass(){

    double[] outBuffer = new double[Synth.bufferSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < Synth.bufferSize; i++){

        outBuffer[i] = (buffer1[i] + buffer2[i])/2;
    }

    synth.passBuffer(outBuffer);
  }
}



package mixer_test;

public class Oscillator  {

WaveShape wave;
boolean hold;
SynthMixer mixer;

public Oscillator(WaveShape wave, SynthMixer mixer){

    this.wave = wave;
    this.mixer = mixer;
    hold = true;

}

public void start(int frequency){


    wave.setFrequency(frequency);

    Thread oscillatorLoop = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            int sampleNo = 0;
            double[] buffer = new double[Synth.bufferSize];

            while(hold){

                for(int i = 0; i < Synth.bufferSize; i++){

                    buffer[i] = wave.getSample(sampleNo + i);
                }

                mixer.sendBuffer(buffer);
                sampleNo += Synth.bufferSize;
            }

        }
    });

    oscillatorLoop.start();
}

public void stop(){
    hold = false;
}

}


package mixer_test;

public class Synth {

public static final int sampleRate = 44100;
public static final int bitDepth = 16;
public static final int bufferSize = 512;


Oscillator osc1, osc2;
SynthMixer mixer;
Amp amp1; // converts double[] to byte[] and writes to SourceDataLine instance

public Synth(){

    mixer = new SynthMixer(this);
    osc1 = new Oscillator(WaveShape.SINE, mixer );
    osc2 = new Oscillator(WaveShape.SINE, mixer);
    amp1 = new Amp();
}

public void passBuffer (double[] buffer){

    amp1.sendBuffer(buffer);
}


public void play(){

    osc2.start(400);
    osc1.start(420);

}

public static void main (String[] args){

    Synth synth = new Synth();
    synth.play();

}
}
```

My thinking when writing this code was as follows:

One of the oscillators lets say Osc A running on Thread A finishes filling a buffer and calls `sendBuffer()`. Thread A holds the `SynthMixer` object lock so even when oscillator on Thread B finishes rendering buffer, it waits before calling `sendBuffer()` until the lock is released. So, Thread A called `sendBuffer()`, buffer1 field is null so the if statement executes writing passed buffer to this field. Then Thread A waits releasing the lock, so Thread B can call the method. Now buffer1 isn't null anymore, so we're writing buffer passed by oscillator B to buffer2 field. `mixAndPass()` takes both buffers and mixes it. After that `notify()` wakes Thread A and the the process repeats for next buffer.

But the effect is that only the signal that gets through is the signal of the oscillator which thread was started last. When debugging the code, I can see that when `wait()` is called, the value of buffer1 suddenly changes to null. I can't understand why it's happening, and would really appreciate an explanation and advice on how to get it working properly.

Comment: To the downvoter. If you're going to downvote and vote to close, comment as to why you think it's off topic...

Comment: Multithreading is a devil.  My hint: don't use the class variables. Use only what's in scope of the method.

Comment: No idea who down-voted but.. Garbage collection possibly? It's really hard to tell. Also, the wall of text is hard to understand. Try making bullet points.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question and vote to close because it is not possible to locally reproduce this behaviour. OP doesn't provide minimal example, `Module` and `Synth` classes are unknown. We can only guess what's happening there, but nobody will be able to fully understand and give useful answer. Until these problems with question content will not be solved, my vote will be -1

Comment: And additional to my previous commentary, description of method `mixAndPass()` omitted as well. This looks like a riddle. I personally do not understand those users, who upvotes this question

Comment: posted code seems to be working fine, problem must be how it is being called or in the methods we can't see

Comment: or the problem could be that 2 instances of `SynthMixer` get created - who knows?

Comment: [wait() should always be called in a loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) that checks the condition which triggered the other thread’s call to notify or notifyAll.  Note that the loop should be inside the try/catch;  the try/catch should not be inside the loop.

Comment: What's the mystery exactly? `wait()` releases the lock, which allows another thread into whatever other synchronized methods you have, and one of them nulls the variable.

Comment: I posted some more code. I called `wait()` in a loop as @VGR suggested, but it causes the sound to stop after few moments (seems to be different every time). When its called without a loop, the sound doesnt break and continues endlessly.

@EJP I dont think thats the case since this class has only one synchronized method (you can see it in my post now).

Comment: This might be much easier with tools like `BlockingQueue`, `Semaphore`, and perhaps `CyclicBarrier` from `java.util.concurrent` rather than `wait()` and `notify()`. Verbum sap.

Comment: @DavidConrad this sounds like a good idea, i'll try this out tommorrow. but still, im curious why this approach doesnt work

Comment: I believe the problem lies elsewhere. That `buffer1` is set to `null` after calling `wait()` is expected behaviour - this is exactly what the other thread does in the else part before calling `notify()`. Your problem is that in the end **both** osc1 and osc2 end up calling `WaveShape.SINE.setFrequency(frequency);` and the last one wins.

Comment: @ThomasKläger this was it. thanks.